# Split big JSON file by type

Tags: powershell

Consider a big JSON in this format(ex: all.json):

```
 [
    {
        "Name": "abc",
        "Type": "movie"
    },
    {
        "Name": "bcd",
        "Type": "series"
    },
        {
        "Name": "asd",
        "Type": "movie"
    },
    {
        "Name": "sdf",
        "Type": "series"
    }
]
```

I want split this file in two files by type

series.json

```
 [
    {
        "Name": "bcd",
        "Type": "series"
    },
    {
        "Name": "sdf",
        "Type": "series"
    }
]
```

movie.json

```
 [
    {
        "Name": "abc",
        "Type": "movie"
    },
        {
        "Name": "asd",
        "Type": "movie"
    }
 ]
```

What is the better approach to do this split using powershell? Someone can help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what you have tried yourself. Note this is *not* a script factory. You will need to write the script yourself. If you run into a problem that isn't yet covered by the existing questions and answers, you might post your [mcve] here so that we might be able to help you further. See also: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
#import data from file
$Array=Get-Content "C:\temp\test.json" | ConvertFrom-Json

#group data by type and export
$Array | group Type | %{

$File="C:\temp\{0}.json" -f $_.Name
$_.Group | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $File
}
```